# Why can't I shout at the graybeards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I got to the graybeards in skyrim I couldn't shout. I checked the controls and it said to hold down RB but it won't work. It does say that I collected a dragon soul and that I unlocked and learned a shout.

Comment: can you shout at all?

Comment: Do you see the shout in the "Shouts" menu? You should also be able to see if you've equipped it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you indeed unlocked the shout, you probably didn't equip it. Go to the magic menu, and you should be able to see and equip it. When this is done, you should be able to shout at the Greybeards when you hold down RB as you said.